# Installing Audacity plugins without administrative privileges

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer, plugins, audacity

Is there a way to direct Audacity in the `Program Files (x86)` folder to look into my flash drive for its plugins?

I am not allowed to change any program files due to lack of administrative privilege, but I have Audacity with my desired plugins on my flash drive. However, I am not able to run it (because it is not in Program Files).

Answer (score 0):

## Official answer

Because of the risks involved in running binaries from unprotected locations, doing such a thing is deliberately not allowed.

## Workaround

[PortableApps.com has a portable copy of Audacity](https://portableapps.com/apps/music_video/audacity_portable) which you can run from your flash drive and had your plug-ins too. Make sure you read [the fineprint about adding LAME and FFMPEG to this version](https://portableapps.com/support/audacity_portable#lame).

Comment: Audacity's official website also has the portable version.

Comment: Yeah, but it does not have help files.